# ANDI accessibility tool not working with ANT Design Modal

Tags: reactjs, antd, andi

I have converted a modal from the unsupported Modali library to Ant Design's modal. The issue I'm having is that the ANDI accessibility tool isn't recognizing the new modal. Was not having this issue with the Modali modal. If I have the new modal open and then open up ANDI, it closes the modal. If I open up the modal after having ANDI open, ANDI doesn't pick up the modal's elements. The work around solution has been opening up the dev tools and finding the modal div wrapper element and moving it inside the ANDI's div wrapper, then without closing ANDI, refreshing ANDI using the built in refresh button. Not sure why the modal div is being rendered outside the ANDI div. Would like a permanent solution then just the work around.[Screen shot of inspected dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElUu8.png)

In the screen shot, you will notice the last unmarked div needs to be moved into the div with the id="ANDI508-testPage", then ANDI recognizes it.

I have searched for the answer and looked at ANDI and Ant design documentation but can't find anything in relation to this issue.